# How to workaround ClientAbortException on iOS12 using XHR (AJAX)?

Tags: ios, ajax, xmlhttprequest, ios12

I’ve been developing a Java-based web application with a JavaScript front-end, and the login scenario goes like this:
1.      Enter username and password;
2.      Receive a notification on another application;
3.      Switch to this application and confirm the authentication request;
4.      Go back to browser and you find yourself logged in.

The tests were good on Android, but when using iPhone, I had this problem where the client (browser) cuts off the HTTP request and, therefore, cannot receive the HTTP response (you can always complete the scenario but nothing happens) and when I consult my server logs, I find this “**ClientAbortException : connection reset**”. (**NOT** "*connection reset by peer*" and **NOT** "*SocketException*")

Anyway, I searched the internet and found that this is an iOS 12 problem (and not yet fixed on iOS 13) and Apple confesses to the bug.
We tried iOS’s Safari, Google Chrome, Firefox and other browsers and all of them had the same problem.

I even tried keeping track of my XHR Requests using an id at step 1, associate that id to the data on the server, then reusing the same id on step 4 to recollect the associated data and I still got the same result.

While researching I found out that the root cause of this problem is that, starting iOS12, Apple decided to cut off background working for applications (optimization issues or something) which also affects browsers sending XHR requests in background. (A solution is available for iOS developpers)

Note: we found another browser called "*iBrowser - Private Web Browser*" that didn't have this issue.

So my question is, if anyone can help me, what is it that keeps the HTTP Session open between this browser and the server ? What could be the difference between it and other browsers ? And, how can I make it work on every other browser ?

Comment: Any luck with this issue, also having problem when implementing SMS based MFA.

Comment: No, not really. In fact, it is fixed on the latest iOS13 beta version, but only on Safari.